# If Vote Leave overspent does that make the referendum invalid?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

There are allegations that vote leave has been linked with additional funds from DUP (Northen Irish party).
An example of this DUP (Northern Irish political party) vote leave advert on metro (popular London (English) paper) after Vote leave have finished their spending.
Ignoring if this is true or not would that make he referendum invalid?

Answer (score 4):

No.
Even if it were a binding vote, which it was not, the breaching of spending laws would not invalidate the vote.